# deprecated pixel format used

Tags: java, ffmpeg

Я получаю видеопоток rtsp и пишу его в файл. Но в логах постоянно валится:

> [swscaler @ 0x7fc171e065a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly`

получаю я такой поток:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709),
  320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp
```

Настройки рекордера:

```
recorder.setVideoCodec(28);
recorder.setFormat("mp4");
recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P);
recorder.setFrameRate(FRAME_RATE);
recorder.setVideoBitrate(10 * 1024 *  1024);
```

Как избавиться от этого предупреждения или отключить логирование у *ffmpeg*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключите логи `av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET)`, подробнее [тут](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.6/log_8h.html).

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос решен

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Comment: Ссылка дана на официальную документацию открытого фреймворка FFMPEG с перечислением ключей логгирования и их расшифровкой. Удаление официальной документации открытого проекта нонсенс.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpegLogCallback.setLevel(AV_LOG_ERROR)

org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.5.6

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]